# Adding a option to dynamically created a select box in js

Tags: javascript

Iam creating a select box and its options dynamically, now i have created options like

```
"passport","license","rta","medicare"
```

I am creating this select box on click of a button...

Now if I click the button for the first time i need to get all the options created, but if i click the button next time the first selected field should not appear or can be graded out, if i select a different field in first select box then this field should appear in the second select box, like this, i should be able to add three select box with unique ooption selected, 
Please help me since I am not able to create it with dynamic id's... ANY HELP WOULD BE GREATLY APPRECIATED!!!!

Comment: [whathaveyoutried....dot com](http://whathaveyoutried.com)